# keyboard and mouse no longer works beyond grub after recent update

Tags: updates, keyboard, ssh, mouse

I recently did a

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and now beyond grub, neither the mouse nor the keyboard (both usb connections) works.  I can fortunately still `ssh` into the machine, and use it that way, but I would like to be able to work on it directly :-)

To be specific, running `setxkbmap -query` returns

```
Cannot open display "default display"
```

For more info:

```
Linux erdos 3.13.0-54-generic #91-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 26 19:15:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C220 Series Chipset Family H81 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Also, I did some digging using `dmesg`

```
[    1.604462] usb 3-2: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[    1.606457] input: PixArt USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input8
[    1.606675] hid-generic 0003:0461:4E22.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0

[    1.417582] usb 3-1: Product: Dell USB Wired Entry Keyboard
[    1.428679] input: Dell Dell USB Wired Entry Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input6
[    1.428735] hid-generic 0003:413C:2111.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Dell Dell USB Wired Entry Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[    1.429961] input: Dell Dell USB Wired Entry Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/input/input7
[    1.430024] hid-generic 0003:413C:2111.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [Dell Dell USB Wired Entry Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1

[   19.156553] usb 3-10: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   26.683353] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   26.783328] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   26.811550] usb 3-10: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

So it seems that something funky is going on with the USB ports, i.e. something is disconnecting them after succesfully recognizing them.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: per [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-trusty/+bug/1437004], it seems I can get the usb, Mouse+Keyboard, to work by essentially plugging them in AFTER the boot.  This is NOT a FIX to the problem, but it is a temporary workaround.

Comment: what happens if you use a PS/2 mouse and keyboard?

Comment: I don't have either of those things.  I just got this new desktop, and it came with a keyboard and mouse, both usb.

Comment: I am actually pretty sure that something in the booting process is disconnecting most of the usb ports; at least this is what I believe the `dmesg` output I posted above is saying.

Comment: Ah. I think you should try using one of the (super cheap by the way) PS/2 to USB adapters @tipanverella

Comment: What happens if you boot with other usb devices plugged in? (i.e. Flash drive, camera, etc.) are those disconnected?

Comment: other devices on usb also get disconnected

Comment: Interesting... Does this happen if you were to boot from the disk on another computer? Does your computer even have a PS/2 port? The PS/2 to USB adapters are [this kind](http://img.tomshardware.com/us/2005/11/23/pc_interfaces_101/ps2_usb.jpg) and a PS/2 port is [this port](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/ps2-ports.jpg) @tipanverella

Comment: my computer does not have a ps/2 port.

Comment: Try this:  Boot up with NO USB devices connected, then after boot, plug stuff in.  If that works, then there's something wrong in your boot sequence.  If not, try to roll back your updates, and file a bug report.

Comment: @Daniel, what you recommended is essentially the first comment on this question.  That is to say that, I have already done this.  I would agree with you that there is something wrong with the boot sequence.  That is what I am trying to address with the question, and why I have put a bounty out for a solution.

Comment: \*facepalm\* Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reboot your PC, enter on the BIOS Setup, search for "USB legacy support" (ASUS Motherboards you can find on "advanced settings") and set as "enabled". Check your motherboard manual or the vendor website.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: That did not resolve the issue.  But it did get me to look in what seems to be the right place, i.e. the BIOS setup.  I had originally setup ubuntu using a usb stick, and had therefore set the boot sequence to first look for a usb drive.  I just undid this, and it seems like it did the trick, i.e. usb ports are now recognized.

Comment: I would love to flag your answer as satisfactory, but I am afraid that it does not actually solve the problem.  Could you submit another answer, saying what I have done, i.e. change the boot sequence?  I feel you deserve the bounty points, but I don't want to confuse future readers looking at this page.

Comment: Be free to edit my answer. I'm so glad to almost help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the discussion on the comments in the other answer, the answer for me was in the BIOS. While legacy USB support had no impact, however the following configuration setting worked for me:

```
Boot Maintenance Manager
Advanced Boot Options
USB Boot Priority: <DISABLED>
```

(Note there was no connected bootable USB device.)